# Which process is accessing which IPs?

Tags: connection, ip, ip-address

After installing Conky and listing all my inbound and outbound connections I start to wonder what's actually happening and what and why things are happening.

[image: screenshot]

I'm getting a bit suspicious. How can I know which process is accessing which of these addresses?

Comment: Wireshark is a better graphical tool for this sort of information then Conky.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - would be nice if you could share a page with know-how related to my question (configuration especially). Wireshark is a huge tool which can do much more than only "sort information". And I use conky mostly for different purposes. In that case it was just a cool feature

Comment: What sort of information do you want ? How to wireshark ? How to interpret network traffic ? How to configure conky ? How to lsof ? netstat ?

Comment: `netstat -nputw`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: To configure wireshark so it solves my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to see those connection that arouse your suspicion you can really use `lsof`.

```
sudo lsof -i | egrep -i "cloudfront|poneytelecom|dark"
```

`lsof -i` restricts the output to internet connections.
Use `egrep` (instead of `grep`) to be able to supply alternatives in the search string (separated by `|`), `-i` tells egrep to ignore case (DARK vs. dark).

If you have IP-addresses instead of hostnames use

```
sudo lsof -ni | egrep -i "10\.0\.8|193\.170"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `lsof -n|grep TCP` to know which programs are connecting to which IPs.

Comment: that only captures some traffic

Comment: Sure, it only shows TCP. You can drop the `|grep TCP` and it will show everything, including all file access and such.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite tool dealing with processes and network usage is `nethogs` (install it with `sudo apt-get install nethogs`).

This tool displays every process and the bandwidth it consumes, it doesn't show the IP-addresses where the processes are connecting though. You may have to start it with the interface name, e.g. `sudo nethogs wlan0`.

[image]

Comment: Even thought it doesn't answer my question to which host the program is connecting I find this answer really useful. I would give it an upvote if I could...